# Mongoose full test search does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to do a full-text search in MongoDB in two fields (body and title).

Model:

```
var newsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
    tags: Array,
    date: Date
});
newsSchema.index({body: 1, title: -1});
var newsModel = mongoose.model('News', newsSchema);
```

Request:

```
var search_text = 'test'; 
newsModel.find({
    $text: {
        $search: search_text
    }
}).then((news) => {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(news));
}).catch((err) => {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

But I get an error `text index required for $text query`. What is the problem?

MongoDB version 3.2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a text index for the field that you're trying to query.
See this https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/#create-text-index for more info. Also see this file https://github.com/gabesoft/dask/blob/master/components/rss/post-model.js from one of my projects on how to create a text index in mongoose